# Need to create file name from text box

Tags: c#

I made a program in which I want to copy a file from one folder to another. But I want to name that file from textbox. I am using below code. Please help me

```
FileInfo receipt = new FileInfo(@"C:\ssds\Receipt.xml");
receipt.CopyTo(@"C:\");
MessageBox.Show("XML Is created");
```

In `receipt.CopyTo` I need to write the name from the text box.

Comment: You should google simple examples of using textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just adding a filename then use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1dzhdx.aspx)

```
receipt.CopyTo(string.Format(@"C:\{0}",textBox1.Text));
```

or [stringConcat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0wkb0y3w.aspx)

```
receipt.CopyTo(string.Concat(@"C:\",textBox1.Text));
```

if it may contain parts of paths or absolute paths (in the case you use some [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)), then Darin's answer using [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.aspx) class is what you need

Answer (score 6):

```
receipt.CopyTo(Path.Combine(@"C:\", textBox1.Text));
```

and if you want to copy the file only to the specified folder, you could extract only the filename from this textbox:

```
receipt.CopyTo(Path.Combine(@"C:\", Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text)));
```

Comment: it is successful but cant see any xml file in the C: folder